# Order of printing errors when piping in bash

Tags: c, bash

So my question is, when you type for example this command in bash `gg/hh | sleep 5 | gg/hh` it prints

```
bash: gg/hh: No such file or directory
bash: gg/hh: No such file or directory
```

then it sleeps. How do you imitate this behavior in C. Because you need to `waitpid(pid, &status, 0)` to get the status of the command you executed in order to print out `No such file or directory`. So how do you get the status of the `execve` in the child process without waiting for sleep to finish.

Comment: Because `sleep` neither reads from stdin nor writes to stdout. Using a pipe does not make sense here.

Comment: Yes but about the order of execution, how does it print the errors first and then sleeps, isn't it supposed to use `waitpid` to wait for the process to finish and then get the error message from waitpids second argument?

Comment: In order for setting up the pipe, the shell needs to locate all 3 commands. If it doesn't find one, it reports an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of execution goes something like this:

1. The shell forks three independent subprocesses (with some interconnected stdins and stdouts): one to run `gg/hh`, another for `sleep 5`, and a third for the other `gg/hh`.
2. *All three run (or try to run) simultaneously*.
3. The shell begins waiting for all three to exit (with `waitpid()` or something similar).
4. The two `gg/hh` processes fail, print their error messages (to stderr, so they go straight to the terminal), and exit. The parent  shell process is not involved in printing these error message, so the fact that it's paused does not matter.
5. Five seconds later, the `sleep 5` process finishes and exits.
6. The parent shell process finishes waiting for its subprocesses, and prompts for a new command.

Note that the `wstatus` that `waitpid()` sets is not related to the error message(s); it's an integer that indicates whether the process succeeded or not, and maybe something about what went wrong. It's used to set the special parameter `$?`, but is not printed.